# Creating an two dimensional array in Crystal

Tags: arrays, initialization, crystal-lang

What is a Crystal equivalent of a Ruby 2d `Array` accessed with indexes like:

```rb
rooms = Array.new(SIZE) { Array.new(SIZE) }
rooms[0][0] = :element
```

I have tried to initialize a 2d `Array` in Crystal in a class:

```rb
class Map
  @rooms : Array(Array(String))

  def initialize
    @rooms[0][0] = 'Test'
  end
end
```

But I get prompted to initialize `@rooms` directly in the `initialize` method:

```bash
Error: instance variable '@rooms' of Map was not initialized directly in all of the 'initialize' methods, rendering it nilable. Indirect initialization is not supported.
```

I have then tried to allocate the `Array` in a nested loop

```rb
@map = Array(Array(Room)).new(SIZE)
    
begin
  (0...SIZE).each do |i|
    @map[i] = Array(Room).new(SIZE)
    (0...SIZE).each do |j|
      room_type = ROOMS.sample
      puts "Create a room '#{room_type}' at cell [#{i}, #{j}]"
      @map[i][j] = Room.new(room_type)
    end
  end
rescue e : IndexError
  puts "Opps: #{e.message}"
end
```

However, this gives me an index of of bound error (`IndexError`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper initialization in Crystal would be something like:

```
Array(Array(String)).new(10) { Array(String).new(10, "") }
```

If you want to start out with `nil`'s as in your Ruby example then you need to make the type nilable:

```
Array(Array(String?)).new(10) { Array(String?).new(10, nil) }
```

Comment: I have realized that the thing I been not doing so far was to initialize the empty element in the inner array initialization. Adding an empty object of the desired type is fixing the problem. So filling the array using the constructor is the only way to allocate it properly before assignment can be done?

Comment: Yes, Ruby is just filling your array implicitly with `nil`s for you when you assign an out of bounds index. Crystal decided to be more explicit here, also due to the elements being typed and thus `nil` possibly being an illegal element value.